# Is there an easily recognized name for this kind of kickstand?

Tags: parts, kickstand

I'm looking for the vocabulary to describe a kind of kickstand that seems pretty much unheard-of where I live. I've seen them particularly on Japanese utility/commuter bikes. The key features are:

- Mounts on the rear fork-end (so it sits clear of the pedals in either raised or lowered position)
- Integrated locking to prevent raising/lowering it by accidental contact
- Double-legged design with the legs joined together at the ground contact area, making a single seamless piece like a large U
- When lowered, lifts the rear wheel off the ground entirely

The Wikipedia page on kickstands includes one photo with an example from a Japanese bike:

[image]

Since that image is rather small, here's something similar being sold on Amazon:

[image]

From [https://www.amazon.com/Fenix-Traditional-Kickstand-Springs-FX-11A/dp/B078NQCTP2/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078NQCTP2) (That page describes it as a "traditional bike kickstand," which is clearly not true since nobody around here has ever seen one!)

Ultimately I'd like to figure out a way to mount a kickstand in this style on my own bike--which may not be possible given the dropout geometry and width of the derailleur--but I'll ask about that in a separate question; for this question I'm just looking for the right vocabulary to ask about such a thing.

How would you explain this so that someone at a bike shop would know what you were talking about without seeing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw the term *drop stand* or *dropstand* being used on quite a few websites to describe this kind of kickstand. Nothing official but still.

Comment: Great, thanks! I think this is the most specific term for it. @Criggie has some good suggestions for the broader class of robust two-axis kickstands that serve the same purpose, but "drop stand" turns up a lot of content related to the exact category I'm talking about. Interestingly, they do seem to be "traditional" in the sense that they were around before the single-prong kickstand was invented or common, so maybe the Amazon description wasn't so off after all!

Answer (score 3):

- Double-sided kickstand
- twin leg kickstand
- dual leg kickstand
- double leg kickstand
  or similar words.

There are also units that fit to the front of the chainstay as well.  These generally lift the front wheel clear of the ground, whereas your design may lift the rear wheel, or it may sit flush leaving 4 points of contact with the ground.

[image]